# Inline assign if else raises error in Python

Tags: python

I am doing some validations and it would be handy (Pythonic?) to write

```
my_variable = value if condition else raise ValueError('Bla bla bla')
```

which I have tried and is not allowed. Any way of doing something similar and avoid the more cumbersome "traditional way"?

```
if condition:
    my_variable = value
else:
    raise ValueError('Bla bla bla')
```

Comment: That's the way to go.

Comment: Please just use the if statement. The conditional expression isn't supposed to replace every use of an if statement.

Comment: I was expecting a more pythonic and human readable alternative to the 4 lines `if` statement :(

Comment: Shorter isn't the same as "more pythonic".

Comment: List comprehensions with `if` conditionals inside are more pythonic than a C like loop?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because an [expression is expected after `else`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), not a statement.

It's possible to workaround this by defining a generic function:

```
def _raise(exception_type, msg):
    raise exception_type(msg)

my_variable = value if condition else _raise(ValueError, 'bla bla')
```

**But** would I do this in real code? probably **not**. It is not as readable as the alternative and it might add a mental overhead while reading the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why would you not do this?

Comment: @user171780 I added some insight